# Is there a way to add styles to my custom Keycloak Email theme?

Tags: html, css, freemarker, keycloak

Title says it all.

I have tried multiple things, but nothing seems to work.

I tried importing a stylesheet in my theme.properties. `styles=css/styles.css`

I tried doing my style directly in my html tags. `<h1 style="color:blue;">`

I tried having my style in my ftl file like so:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.header{
    background-color: #B70E0C;
    width: 100%;
    height: 96px;
}

.footer{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.footer a {
    color: white !important;
}

a:visited {
    color: initial;
}

.activate-btn{
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 12px 28px;
    background-color: #FDC300;
    color: black;
    border-style: hidden;
}
</style>
<body>
${kcSanitize(msg("emailVerificationBodyHtml", link, linkExpiration, realmName, 
linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration)))?no_esc}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Composing html email is not a simple thing like composing html web page, since almost all email services process incoming email in different ways. Some may ignore <style ..> refs, some may ignore several css properties. To make a crossplatform email (which will be rendered same in Gmail, Outlook, Thunderbird etc..) you will have to rollback to 2000's technologies like page layout based on tables, inlined css styles like `<p style="..">` so you'd better look to email frameworks like [Zurb](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/email-templates.html).

With [zurb](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/sass-guide.html) you can create and debug your email templates in browser like any other UI application from npm world. Then you can slice Zurb output to keycloak freemarker templates. At the end you'll got main freemarker template (with common headers, bottom links etc..), and bunch of freemarker macroses for paragraphs, links... This сomponents will encapsulate all ugliness like inlined css, tables etc, so your business templates will be simple and look pretty nice. This is what i got for **execute required actions** email

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.emailLayout title=msg('executeActionsSubject')?no_esc; section>

    <#if section = "header">
        <@layout.header text=msg("executeActionsSubject")?no_esc icon="status-icon-green%403x.png"/>

    <#elseif section = "content">

        <#outputformat "plainText">
            <#assign requiredActionsText>
                <#if requiredActions??>
                    <ul>
                    <#list requiredActions>
                        <#items as reqActionItem><li>${msg("requiredAction.${reqActionItem}")}</li></#items>
                    </#list>
                    </ul>
                </#if>
            </#assign>
        </#outputformat>

        <@layout.paragraph>
            ${msg("executeActionsBodyIntro", realmName)?no_esc}
        </@layout.paragraph>

        <b>
            ${msg("executeActionsList", requiredActionsText)?no_esc}
        </b>

        <@layout.paragraph>
            ${msg("executeActionsClickLinkNote")?no_esc}
        </@layout.paragraph>

        <@layout.mainAction text=msg("executeActionsButtonText")?no_esc href=link/>

        <@layout.secondaryText>
            ${kcSanitize(msg("expirationNote", linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration)))?no_esc}
        </@layout.secondaryText>

        <@layout.secondaryText>
            ${msg("mistakeDeleteText")?no_esc}
        </@layout.secondaryText>

    </#if>

</@layout.emailLayout>
```

UPD. There is also other frameworks for emails composing. For example
[MJML](https://mjml.io/). Anyway development flow is completely the same for any of this frameworks, so feel free to use any of them.

Comment: This does look like the way to go, I'm just not too sure about the "can slice Zurb output to keycloak freemarker templates" part. Is there a way to do that automatically ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but it is not so hard as it seems. Just begin to create layout and test it as web-page with Zurb (Note that Zurb also allows to have general skeleton template, so other email layouts can inherit it and modify only "business content"). As for me it takes me only one full work day to create Zurb layouts for all keycloak emails in my company. And another one day to port them to freemarker and debugging. It's not bad if take to account that i am not a frontend guy.

Comment: @solveMe did you achieved  proper email template with the given solution, I also need to create reset password email template?

Comment: Can you please show your template.ftl file is it kind of skeleton created by Zurb?

Comment: @YachithaSandaruwan unfortunately it was on my previous job, so I don't have access to sources anymore(

Comment: @solveMe you did create template.ftl by using Zurb?

Comment: @YachithaSandaruwan I created several layouts via zurb (zurb also allows you to create base template for header, logo, bottom links). Then I tested it with browser (check zurb docs for running testing/preview mode). When I was satisfied with result I run Zurb build and get final output for emails. Next step is to extract some parts of this messy output and compose a template.ftl and other macroses (e.g. for paragraphs) from it. Key hint: to detect bounds of your strucure elements in final output you should thoroughly comment them when you use Zurb markup.

Comment: @solveMe Thanks a lot, I had done my first email template edit and which was succeeded. You are so amazing. Thanks again for your hints.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #B70E0C;
  width: 100%;
  height: 96px;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #2D2D2D;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer a {
  color: white !important;
}

a:visited {
  color: initial;
}

.activate-btn {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  background-color: #FDC300;
  color: black;
  border-style: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:blue;">lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
${kcSanitize(msg("emailVerificationBodyHtml", link, linkExpiration, realmName, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration)))?no_esc}
<p style="color:red;">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: This only works for the content outside the kcSanitize.